# Java Random Class nextDouble() Parameters

Tags: java

I understand that from the manual (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) that .nextDouble() does not accept parameters. However, in this case, it returns both correct value between "return (max - min) * randomPT.nextDouble();" and "return randomPT.nextDouble(max - min);". I would like to understand the reason to why this works but I can't seem to figure out

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Random;

class RandomPoint extends Point{
  private static Random randomPT = new Random(1);

  public RandomPoint(double minX, double maxX, double minY, double maxY){
    super(generateRandomCoordinate(minX, maxX), generateRandomCoordinate(minY, maxY));
  }

  private static double generateRandomCoordinate(double min, double max) {
    return (max - min) * randomPT.nextDouble();
    //return randomPT.nextDouble(max - min);
  }

  // Set the seed for the pseudo-random number generator
  public static void setSeed(long newSeed) {
    randomPT.setSeed(newSeed);
  }
}
```

Maybe was expecting some error when nextDouble receives a parameter?

Comment: Could it be that the parameter is auto discarded? since when I try "return randomPT.nextDouble();", it works the same

Comment: What version of Java are you using? The documentation you quoted is for Java 8. `nextDouble` can take 1 or 2 parameters since Java 17 if I remember correctly.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 both (`default`) methods are implemented in [`RandomGenerator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html#nextDouble(double)) since Java 17, which is implemented by `java.util.Random`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Random implements RandomGenerator.

Comment: Gack! I didn't scrolll enough. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JDK version 17 or later, you will find the method you're referring to. This method isn't mentioned in the JDK 8 documentation because it was introduced in JDK 17. The method in question is an overloaded version of nextDouble with parameters, which is part of the RandomGenerator interface. This interface was added to the Random class in JDK 17. Internally, RandomGenerator delegates the task of generating random numbers to the RandomSupport class. The implementation note in the documentation provides insight into how this works:

> Implementation Note: The result from a call to nextDouble is
> multiplied by the specified bound. If this result is not less than the
> bound (a situation that can occasionally occur due to rounding), it is
> adjusted to be the largest double value that is less than the bound.

So, when you call random.nextDouble(bound), the execution flow is as follows: Random#nextDouble(bound) -> RandomGenerator#nextDouble(bound) -> RandomSupport#boundedNextDouble(this, bound).

Within the RandomSupport#boundedNextDouble method, the code essentially does this:

```
double r = rng.nextDouble();
r = r * bound;
```

This internal method implementation aligns with what you are doing in your example: multiplying nextDouble() with a value, which in this case is the 'bound' parameter. As a result, you get the same behavior.

Moreover, to ensure truly random values, it's important to consider the seed value when creating your Random instance. This is crucial for achieving sufficient entropy. In your case, you're consistently seeding with the value 1, which produces a pseudo-random sequence. While this might be acceptable for testing purposes, varying the seed value is essential for generating a broader range of random numbers in other applications.